# Plasma diagnostics - Langmuir probe

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, temperature, plasma-physics

I was wondering how the position (changing the radial distance) of the single cylindrical Langmuir probe in the chamber tube affects the measured results. I was measuring the electron temperature etc. to obtain the EEDF (electron energy distribution function) but the data differ for different positions of the probe in the chamber tube and I really don't know why and what is going on. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you elaborate here and describe things in more detail?  Also, can you spell out acronyms/initialisms?  For instance, no one here is going to know what is meant by "...the tube..." in regards to where the probe is located.  What tube?  The chamber where the experiment is taking place or is there a tube used to protect the probe?

Comment: I have made some adjustments

Comment: To what does EEDF refer?

Comment: My bad: Electron energy distribution function

Comment: Okay, so when you talk about positioning the probe in the chamber tube, are you talking about varying the radial location or the axial or both?  There are lots of reasons to think the electron profile will change with both (e.g., axial distance from source matters greatly).

Comment: I change randial distance

Comment: Presumably the source is in the center of your chamber tube?  If so, and the magnetic field is axially aligned, would you expect the electron distribution to be uniform with respect to radial distance from the center?

Comment: Probably not I would expect more electrons with higher energy in the center. But I have a hard time imagining how that plasma actually looks like inside.